# Do i need hyper-v or HAXM or WHPX for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hyper-v, haxm

Ive installed HAXM , an can also enable Hyper-v and WHPX. The android studio documentation about this is confusing me. What do I need have enabled and disabled.

Comment: It is required for the Android emulators. If you want to use an emulator or if your emulator is not working, then bother with the settings, else ignore it. Also, enabling Hyper-V is enough, you can toggle it in bios settings.